# What can I do to improve performance of rsync when run on SMR drives (shingled drives)?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, external-hard-drive, filesystems, rsync

When syncing with `rsync` to or from SMR drives performance drops to a minimum of 3 to 5 mb/s, with noticeable head flying noise.

This is especially unexpected if `rsync` only reads the SMR drive.  Reading data written in a shingled manner should be comparable in performance to PMR drives (perpendicular magnetic recording drives).

Any of the popular filesystems seem to exhibit similar behavior.

What—if anything—can be done to improve `rsync` performance on SMR drives (shingled drives)?

Answer (score 2):

If you `rsync` **from** an SMR drive, make sure that filesystem is mounted `read-only` or with `noatime` option.

Otherwise the SMR drive will need to write a timestamp for each file rsync reads, resulting in a significant performance degradation (from around 80 mb/s down to 3-5 mb/s here) and head wear / clicking noise.

If you already have an rsync job running with poor performance, there is no need to stop it, you can remount the source filesystem doing

```
sudo mount -o remount,ro  /path/to/source/fs
```

The effect will not be seen immediately, be patient and wait 10 to 20 minutes, until the drive has finished to write out all the data still in its buffers.  This advise is tried and tested ok.

---

This might also apply when `rsync`ing **to** an SMR drive, i.e. if the filesystem tries to update the timestamp after the file has been fully written to disk.  This jitters sequential workload and huge bands of data are continuously rewritten, contributing to drive wear.  The following *may* help:

```
sudo mount -t fs_type -o rw,noatime device /path/to/dest/fs
```

This has to be done, before rsync is run; other factors may render this option insignificant, i.e. unbuffered FAT/MFT updating, parallelized writes if the filesystem is optimized primarily for SSDs, etc.

---

Try to use `dd bs=32M` and then resize the filesystem on the SMR target, if you want to backup full filesystems anyway (no need to have it mounted and run rsync to transport each and every file in this case).

---

Exemplary hardware in use here was a Seagate drive managed SMR 8tb consumer drive.  Your mileage may vary with other hardware.

Answer (score 1):

For SMR rsync backups to a for a Seagate 4TB "Expansion Portable Drive"  I've found I need to throttle the rsync by using rsync's `--bwlimit` option to stop it overrunning the SMR's cache/fast-write-zone.

I'm currently setting `--bwlimit` to something between 15MB/sec and 30MB/sec depending on workload, for example

```
mount -o noatime,nodiratime,data=writeback /dev/mapper/usbluks /mnt/usbbackup
rsync -a -HAX --sparse --bwlimit=20M /home/ /mnt/usbbackup/
```

It also possible to used `systemd-run` to limit the IO bandwidth:

```
systemd-run -tP --wait -p "IOWriteBandwidthMax=/mnt/usbbackup 30M" rsync -a -HAX --sparse /home/ /mnt/usbbackup/
```

I'm mounting my LUK's ext4 filesystem `data=writeback` in an attempt to let the drive optimise the writes.  I think that's helping, but at some risk if the power goes out.

If the drive does throttle back to lower than 1MB/sec, I sometimes suspend the job for a while and let the hard drive sort itself out. I normally run the external backups in a terminal, so I can easily control-z and fg it as necessary.

As well as finishing with a sync or two, I tend to let the drive sit for quite some time in case it's still sorting itself out in respect to it's fast-write-zone.

There is also rsync `--fsync` option that can further throttle the copying, but it might break up small writes and I'm not sure if that is a good idea.

I've only recently come to realise that SMR was the cause of my backups grinding to a crawl, so this is all a bit experimental.